# c++ array size and how to manage large array?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I try to use sieve method to find how many prime numbers from 1 to 100000.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *a = new char[100000];
    memset(a, '1', 100000*sizeof(char));

    for(int i=2; i<100000; i++)
    {
         if(a[i] == '1')
         {
              for(int j=i*i; j<100000; j += i)
              {
                   a[j] = '0';
              }
         }
    }

    int count = 0;
    for(int i=2; i<100000; i++)
    {
         if(a[i] == '1')
              count++;
    }
    cout << count << endl;

    delete [] a;
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles without error,but when i run it,the program crash.

I change the array size from 100000 to 40000.I get the result 4203,so there are 4203 prime numbers from 1 to 40000

I know the maximum byte of array in my 32 bit operating system is 0x7fffffff bytes.

Either 100000 chars or 40000 chars is much less than  0x7fffffff bytes.

why when array size is 100000,the program carsh.when array size is 40000,the program work? Is there any wrong with my code?

Comment: Since this is C++, why not std::vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an integer overflow issue.

You assign `j = i*i`. When `i` is equal to `99999`,  `i*i` is `9999800001`, which is most likely higher than `INT_MAX` on your platform. On a 32-bit platform, `INT_MAX` is `2147483647`, which is lower than `9999800001`.

Here they are in two rows for comparison:

```
2147483647
9999800001
```

Due to integer overflow, your program has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
for(int j=i*i; j<100000; j += i)
```

`i*i` is out of bounds and j overflows and becomes negative making this line:

```
a[j] = '0';
```

segfault

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use arrays at all? You could consider using a simpler algorithm such as:

```
#include  <iostream>
using  namespace  std;

    int  main()
    {
      int  N;
      int count = 0;
      cin >> N;
      for (int i = 2; N > 0; ++i)
      {
        bool  isPrime = true;
        for (int j = 2; j < i; ++j)
        {
          if (i  % j == 0)
          {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (isPrime)
        {
          if (i > N)
            break;
          count++;
          cout << i << "\n";
        }
      }
      cout << "The number of primes from 0 to " << N << " is " << count << endl;

      char stop;
      cin >> stop;
      return  0;
    }
```

This algorithm outputs 9592 as the number of primes from 0 to 100000.

Answer (score 1):

All of the other answers about overflow are correct.

To answer a potential follow-up question: how could I avoid/detect this in the first place?  Well, some compilers can provide runtime detection for undefined behavior.

Here's what I get when I run your code with UBSan ([what is UBSan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html)?):

```
$ clang++ -fsanitize=undefined  overflow.cpp 
$ ./a.out 
overflow.cpp:14:26: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 46349 * 46349 cannot be represented in type 'int'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

For reference, line #14 is this one:

```
          for(int j=i*i; j<100000; j += i)
```

Comment: I can figure out the problem next time by myself, Thank you!